# AWS Lambda getting file from S3 then using it

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I need to pull 2 files from my S3 and use them in a HttpAgent and I and struggling to find the correct method.  Using SDKv3 which is returning a ReadableStream.

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

async (event, context) => {
  let options;
  let httpsAgent;
  try {
    console.log('> Getting content from S3');
    const s3Client = new S3Client({
      region: 'us-east-2',
    });
    let command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Key: 'lib/myCert.crt',
      Bucket: 'mybucket',
    });
    console.log('>>Getting Cert command');
    const hcert = await s3Client.send(command);
   

    command = new GetObjectCommand({
      Key: 'lib/myKey.pem',
      Bucket: 'mybucket',
    });
    console.log('Get Key');
    const ckey = await s3Client.send(command);
  
    console.log('initializing Agent');
    httpsAgent = new https.Agent(
      {
        key: ckey.Body.pipe(createWriteStream('/tmp/myKey.pem')),
        cert: hcert.Body.pipe(createWriteStream('/tmp/myCert.crt')),
        // key: fs.readFileSync('./tmp/myKey.pem'),
        // cert: fs.readFileSync('./tmp/myCert.crt'),
        keepAlive: true
      }
    );
```

With the above code I get a ParameterNotFound.  I have tried writing to the disk then accessing ( via fs.ReadFileSync) it but same issue.

Comment: Can you share the complete error you're getting? `ParameterNotFound` is a bit too generic to start looking into the issue.

Comment: It turns out the Parameter not found error was with another part of the Lambda because some old code got mixed in.  i ended up solving it by changing them into strings and sending them but I would love to figure out why I could not write it into /tmp and then read it.